# Chunks of an Array of objects using an object property as the "delimiter"

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, lodash, chunks

Given the following array:

```
var arr = [{id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:12},
           {id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:5}];
```

How can I use lodash, to split the array each time code is not equal to 0 and get the following results?

```
[
 [{id:1 , code:0},{id:1 , code:12}],
 [{id:1 , code:0},{id:1 , code:0},{id:1 , code:5}]
]
```

Comment: I can suggest a short working solution on pure JS, if you're interested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` (or lodash's `_.reduce()`) for this:

```js
var arr = [{id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:12},
           {id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:5}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(result, item, index, arr) {
  index || result.push([]); // if 1st item add sub array
  
  result[result.length - 1].push(item); // add current item to last sub array
  
  item.code !== 0 && index < arr.length - 1 && result.push([]); // if the current item code is not 0, and it's not the last item in the original array, add another sub array
  
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can get rid of `index || result.push([]);` if you just start the reduce with `[[]]`

Comment: Nope - if the original array is empty, the result would be `[[]]`.

Answer (score 3):

A solution in plain Javascript with a single loop without mutating the original array.

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1, code: 0 }, { id: 1, code: 12 }, { id: 1, code: 0 }, { id: 1, code: 0 }, { id: 1, code: 5 }],
    grouped = arr.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var l = r[r.length - 1];
        if (!i || l[l.length - 1].code) {
            r.push([a]);
        } else {
            l.push(a);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative "native" JS solution using `Array.splice` function:

```js
var arr = [{id:1 , code:0},{id:1 , code:12}, {id:1 , code:0},{id:1 , code:0}, {id:1 , code:5}],
    chunks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].code !== 0 && chunks.push(arr.splice(0, i + 1));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(chunks, 0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in the result if you expect reduced number elements then i guess you just have to reduce.

```js
var arr = [{id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:12},
           {id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:0},
           {id:1 , code:5}],
reduced = arr.reduce((red,obj) => !obj.code ? red[red.length-1].length === 1 ||
                                              red[red.length-1].length === 0 ? (red[red.length-1].push(obj),red)
                                                                             : red.concat([[obj]])
                                            : (red[red.length-1].push(obj),red),[[]]);
console.log(reduced);
```